# ars3wapi32.dll: Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform

Tags: ondemand

Running the Java IBM ODwek API, I encountered the error 
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: ars3wapi32.dll: Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform.

If you have this same issue, relax as I will guide through the resolution.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I identified the various elements that could potentially result to this issue.

- Java Library Path is identifying the 32bit path of the library file.
- 32bit ars3wapi32.dll is refered instead of ars3wapi64.dll.

By default for ODwek 9.0 library path is C:\Program Files\ibm\OnDemand Web Enablement Kit\V9.0\lib32 if the ODwek Path is not specified the PATH env variable.

**Resolution**:
In V9.0: you must specify in your CLASSPATH the odwek library (64bit) path C:\Program Files\ibm\OnDemand Web Enablement Kit\V9.0\lib64 and its home path C:\Program Files\ibm\OnDemand Web Enablement Kit\V9.0\

[image]